# Trouble hiding a 3D Object on a Ground Plane in Unity and vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hide, vuforia

I'm a beginner in Unity and Vuforia. I have a 3D object placed on a ground plane, and I'm trying to hide it using the SetActive(false) method when a button is clicked. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected when I click the button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Vuforia;

public class ARController : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject obj;

    public void hideIT()
    {
        
        obj.SetActive(false);
    }

   
}
```

Tried SetActive(false) on 3D object, expected hide, got no change.

Comment: And the 3D object you assign to `GameObject obj` via the inspector lives the whole time in the scene or is it instantiated at some point and you referenced the _prefab_ of the 3D object here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your public method is called when the button is clicked. To do this, you can use the inspector window with your `Button` component on it and using OnClick () field.Add new field and drag and drop your class to it, then select class and method from the pop-up list (in your case, hideIT). Now every time you press your button if GameObject will be active it will be hided on scene. You can also directly access the button through the code. Create a `Public Button hideBtn` field and add `hideBtn.OnClick.AddListener(hideIT)` in the Awake method.

Answer (score 0):

I want to let you know that the issue concerns the plane finder. I was activating  the 'duplicate stage' button, but when I turned this off, the 'hide' button starts working. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7dX9.png)

Comment: please edit your original question instead of clarifying the question in an answer